# Highcharts - how to wrap y-axis title in styled mode

Tags: highcharts

Can someone help me to wrap y-axis title please (I am using styled mode)?
Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/6s3wa0m7/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        styledMode: true,
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'test'
    },

    yAxis: [{
        className: 'highcharts-color-0',
        title: {
            text: 'very long title text here very long title text here very long title text here very long title text here '
        }
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            borderRadius: 5
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
    }, {
        data: [324, 124, 547, 221],
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below CSS styles:

```
    .highcharts-axis-title {
        width: 200px;
        white-space: normal !important;
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gqud6c0L/

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion but, unfortunately I can't use `useHTML` because it doesn't work for exported png. Is there any other solution? Also my chart height is not static.

Comment: Hi @Sabira, You can dynamically set a witdh for the title, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/13e6dbxz/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!